# compress a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I obfuscate JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)

I want my js not to be understood by anyone. I have read some similar posts on this site but can get an exe or a full desktop application for it. Whatever I get are online tools.

OR how to sense '\n' character in js?

Comment: What's wrong with using an online tool?

Comment: You may find these questions helpful: [How can I obfuscate JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript) and [Does JavaScript obfuscation provide much intellectual property protection for your code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252484/does-javascript-obfuscation-provide-much-intellectual-property-protection-for-yo)

Answer (score 1):

[UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) / [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2):

JavaScript parser / mangler / compressor / beautifier toolkit

Comment: Hey Thanx a lot but what is npm? Is it something specific to an OS?

Comment: no. its the nodejs package manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can download "yui compressor" to compress the javascript. But I does not means that no-one can read you scripts.

Their are again tool which make your compressed javascript files again readable :(